# Difference between CTEs in MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, cte

This is probably a bit of a lazy question, but I would appreciate any quick pointers.

I have used CTEs considerably in PostgreSQL. I know that since 8.0 MySQL supports CTEs and now I want to take a closer look at it (even though I have no intention of actually using it in practice).

I will probably be going through some manuals and tutorials very soon, but any quick pointers will be nice also - are there any major differences between CTEs in MySQl vs. Postgres?

Can I simply copy paste a CTE query from Postgres into MySQL (assuming identical underlying tables) and expect it to work?

Comment: The main difference I can think of: MySQL does not support DML in CTEs. Query optimization is most like different between the two as well. You probably also want to check if MySQL also supports `search breadth/depth first` and the `cycle` option for recursive CTEs

Comment: It supports BFS and DFS, based on the post I'm looking at https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-1-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes-part-four-depth-first-or-breadth-first-traversal-transitive-closure-cycle-avoidance/

Comment: PostgreSQL does not support multiple recursive queries in CTE also. Rather than MySQL.

Comment: @dakini *It supports BFS and DFS* No, MySQL implements BFS only. See https://dbfiddle.uk/SBccW0MA

Comment: Also - in MySQL you can refer to CTE in each recursive query only once and only in FROM (no self-joins, no subqueries and so on).

Comment: PostgreSQL supports SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE following a CTE. MySQL supports SELECT, UPDATE, and DELETE following a CTE. MariaDB is not MySQL, it has a different implementation, and only allows SELECT.

Comment: @BillKarwin: Postgres also also allows SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE _inside_ a CTE

Comment: Yes, I realized after I wrote my comment that's what you were talking about, so I edited my comment to be about another difference between the two implementations.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry to say that MySQL doesn't support `cycle` for recursive CTEs.